# SQL Server 2012 8k limitation confusion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about the SQL Server 8k limitation. I have a destination table with 453 columns, all are of `type varchar(max)`. My import table also has same number of columns and of same datatype. Basically Import table -> destination table. I am sure ppl are going to suggest normalizing and redesign but I am more interested in why sql server is behaving this way.

The character count of the rows from import table are around 4000 and 4500. Below are the senarios I need help with

1. If I do a `select * into sometable from "import table"`, I get a successful run.
2. If I do a `insert into "destination table" select * from "import table"` I get an error saying `"Cannot create a row of size 8239 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060."`

I am totally losing my mind. I thought using `varchar(max)` allows me to stretch the 8060 limitation upto 2 gig. All my destination table columns and import table columns are of type varchar(max) which allows for LOB and/or out-of-row storage.

Need help please.

Comment: *Discussion* questions aren't really on-topic on any stack exchange site. Could you please remove the relevant portion of the text, and then ask for the question to be migrated to the database site in the stack exchange network?

Comment: Lasse, does it look better. this is my SOF post so pls bear with me :-)

Comment: Definitely :) but still probably better off on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com), so you might want to flag it for migration.

Comment: Is the primary difference between your working query and non-working query that, for the first, `sometable` didn't already exist? If so, it could be important to know what *indexes* `destination_table` may have.

Comment: Can you double check that all columns are VARCHAR(MAX). If they are can you show more of your code as rows can be greater than 8060, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5604/1. Also see this great post on the subject of VARCHAR(MAX) https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar(n)-anymore/

Comment: SQLfiddle won't let me post my sql since its more than 8000 chars :-(. @Damie, sometable didn't exist.

Comment: @steve, Yes all the columns are varchar(max) in both destination_table and import_Table.

Comment: I have pasted my entire sql source code to http://shrib.com/aXswUqWt

Comment: @steve I have read the link you have sent, infact I think I have read pretty much all the 8k discussion/blog but nothing answers my questions!! Also, the sql code I posted pls use "sometable" as destination_table and "ioioio" as import_table.

Comment: Did you use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR in your destination table?

Comment: More info is needed. I have SQL 2012, ran your DDL, and inserted 2 of your sample rows (after removing ~16 columns as the sample data has ~470 fields and the table has only 454). I could do both `SELECT * INTO FROM` and `INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM`. No problems. I checked the table definition after using `SELECT * INTO` and all fields were VARCHAR(MAX), as expected. I suggest going row by row (`WHERE [id] = XX`), maybe start with ranges to narrow down (`WHERE [id] BETWEEN XX AND YY`), doing the `INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM` to identify a row that won't work and update shrib.com with that row.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried row by row and I still get error. I am using SQL server version 11.0.3128. What is yours?